# Can a method call be instrumented with ByteBuddy instead of the called method?

Tags: java, scala, aspectj, byte-buddy

I would like to replace some AspectJ code that protects calls to `java.lang.System` from some user code.
`java.lang.System` cannot/should not be instrumented.

With AspectJ the solution is to instrument the calling code like the following example. The code that should be guarded will be instrumented while the code that is allowed is not.

```
@Around("call(public long java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()) && within(io.someuserdomain..*) && !within(io.someotherdomain..*))
def aroundSystemcurrentTimeMillis(wrapped: ProceedingJoinPoint): Long = {
      throw new IllegalStateException("must not call System.currentTimeMillis in usercode")
}
```

Is there a way to do the same using ByteBuddy? So far I only found examples on how to instrument the callee instead of the caller.

Comment: Why do you wish to replace AspectJ by ByteBuddy? The AspectJ runtime is much smaller and has no other dependencies. What is the problem you are trying to solve by switching the tool?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to quantify my previous statement: The AspectJ runtime has 120K, ByteBuddy with packaged dependencies 3.2M. Comparing the JARs of current versions, the JAR size differs by a factor of 27.5 in favour of AspectJ. That does not mean it is the better tool, but for what you want to do it is well suited. If using compile-time weaving, you can even declare compiler warnings or errors in an aspect in order to make compilation fail if the aspect detects illegal method calls. I would do it that way if CTW is an option as opposed to LTW because detecting it during runtime is suboptimal.

Comment: @kriegaex Good question. We are using another library that switched from aspectj to bytebuddy (kamon). In our codebase we use aspectj quiet sparingly and want to avoid having multiple instrumentation frameworks maintained.
As for the discussed usecase - if this would be the only place I need instrumentation I would opt for aspectj because it allows for more flexibility. But I'm of course biased having used aspectj a lot and I'm new to bytebuddy. On the other places that I converted from aspectj to bytebuddy the typesafety of the instrumentation declaration in bytebuddy is nicer than aspectj.

Comment: I am surprised you say that about type safety. Actually, I see a lot of bad aspect code out there from people not experienced enough to use AspectJ correctly, so maybe that is where it comes from. Having said that and admitting my pro-AspectJ bias because I use it all the time, I do agree that ByteBuddy is a powerful tool and have no doubts that you will solve your problems elegantly with it too. Rafael's answer looks very good to me and he provides great support here on SO, being the ByteBuddy author. :-) Good luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

You can currently replace a method or field access by registering a `MemberSubstitution` but the capabilities are still limited compared to AspectJ. It is for example not possible to throw an exception as in your example code. You can however delegate to a method that would contain the code that throws the exception:

```
MemberSubstitution.relaxed()
  .method(named("currentTimeMillis"))
  .replaceWith(MyClass.class.getMethod("throwException"))
  .in(any());
```

The above substitution would replace any method call with a call to the following member:

```
public class MyClass {
  public static long throwException() {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  }
}
```

The substitution would be applied to any method onto which the visitor is applied. You can register an `AgentBuilder.Default` to build a Java agent to do so or have a look into Byte Buddy's build plugins.

Comment: Thx a lot for the fast reply!
Unfortunately I'm stuck with applying this example.

`new ByteBuddy().redefine(EvilCode.getClass).visit(MemberSubstitution.relaxed.method(ElementMatchers.hasMethodName("currentTimeMillis")).replaceWith(Thrower.getClass.getMethod("throwException")).on(ElementMatchers.any())).make()`

this throws a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke public long Thrower$.throwException() on []`

Detailed gist is here: https://gist.github.com/danischroeter/29c418d9f0b73af4d901e93fff3ba2a6

Comment: Hmm the IllegalStateException seems to be an issue using a static method from a scala object where ByteBuddy found the parameters to be incompatible because of the INSTANCE field of the object...
By declaring a plain java class the exception is not thrown...

Comment: I got the example to run without failing but my test still fails (instrumenting did not catch the call)  
https://gist.github.com/danischroeter/29c418d9f0b73af4d901e93fff3ba2a6
  
bytebuddy did change something:
`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended`
  
but the Thrower was not called
`Expected exception java.lang.RuntimeException to be thrown, but no exception was thrown`

Comment: Did you register an AgentBuilder.Listener in your agent to see if the class is correctly instrumented?